# Sublime Text 3 Missing Extensions

Tags: sublime-text-3, file-extension, syntax

I started using sublime text v3 and I'm having problems with some extensions. When I look for php/js/css/html extensions, they aren't listed in the extensions list. I reinstalled the program and they're still missing. How
do I fix this?

[the existing extensions. (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmhAv.png)

Comment: What "extensions list" are you looking at?

Comment: @MattDMo the whole languages that sublime can identify. If the sublime won't idenify the extension of the file, it'll syntax as a plain text. I see "Plain text" at right of the bottom of the sublime. When I click it I get the whole extensions.

Comment: Can you see any languages when you click lower right corner (where you see Plain text now) ?

Comment: @Todd Yes I see (e.g. ActionScript, C, C#, Java, Pascal, MATLAB and on..)

Comment: @Eliya when you save a file with an extension of say 'js', does Sublime Text display it with 'js' highlighting or stays as 'Plain Text'?

Comment: @Todd it stays as 'Plain Text'. I tried to download the portable version and I found out that the Portable Version had the folder "Data", So I tried to copy the "Data" Folder the the installed folder and it worked.. I honestly dunno what I've done there..

Answer (score 0):

In your account's home directory open your application data or "application support" folder in Mac OS, then locate your Sublime Text folder. There should be a Cache subfolder in there, delete its contents, then quit and restart Sublime Text.